# Unable to bring up Eclipse che on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, eclipse-che

Getting ERR_TIMEOUT: Timeout set to pod wait timeout 300000 while dowloading images

I am new to Eclipse che and kubernetes. I got Kubernetes installed on Ubuntu and am trying to run chectl server:start but it is failing. What am doing wrong? Below is the trace i get. Is there a log file where i could get more details? Please help.

Details:

```
✔ Verify Kubernetes API...OK
✔  Looking for an already existing Che instance
✔ Verify if Che is deployed into namespace "che"
✔ Found running che deployment
✔ Found running plugin registry deployment
✔ Found running devfile registry deployment
✔  Starting already deployed Che
✔ Scaling up Che Deployments...done.
❯ ✅ Post installation checklist
❯ Che pod bootstrap
✔ scheduling...done.
✖ downloading images
→ ERR_TIMEOUT: Timeout set to pod wait timeout 300000
starting
Retrieving Che Server URL
Che status check
Error: ERR_TIMEOUT: Timeout set to pod wait timeout 300000
at KubeHelper.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/chectl/lib/api/kube.js:578:19)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/chectl/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:107:62)
```

Values.yaml

```
#
# Copyright (c) 2012-2017 Red Hat, Inc.
# This program and the accompanying materials are made
# available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License 2.0
# which is available at https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0
#

# the following section is for secure registries. when uncommented, a pull secret will be created
#registry:
#  host: my-secure-private-registry.com
#  username: myUser
#  password: myPass

cheWorkspaceHttpProxy: ""
cheWorkspaceHttpsProxy: ""
cheWorkspaceNoProxy: ""
cheImage: eclipse/che-server:nightly
cheImagePullPolicy: Always
cheKeycloakRealm: "che"
cheKeycloakClientId: "che-public"
#customOidcUsernameClaim: ""
#customOidcProvider: ""
#workspaceDefaultRamRequest: ""
#workspaceDefaultRamLimit: ""
#workspaceSidecarDefaultRamLimit: ""

global:
  cheNamespace: ""
  multiuser: false
  #  This value can be passed if custom Oidc provider is used, and there is no need to deploy keycloak in multiuser mode
  #  default (if empty) is true
  #cheDedicatedKeycloak: false
  ingressDomain: <xx.xx.xx.xx.nip.io>
  # See --annotations-prefix flag (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md)
  ingressAnnotationsPrefix: "nginx."
  # options: default-host, single-host, multi-host
  serverStrategy: multi-host
  tls:
    enabled: false
    useCertManager: true
    useStaging: true
    secretName: che-tls
  gitHubClientID: ""
  gitHubClientSecret: ""
  pvcClaim: "1Gi"
  cheWorkspacesNamespace: ""
  workspaceIdleTimeout: "-1"
  log:
    loggerConfig: ""
    appenderName: "plaintext"
```

Comment: share your deployment YAML

Comment: Please provide information like: 
1. How did you install Kubernetes?
2. Exact command that was invoked to start Che server.

Comment: Che server was started with chectl server:start command. Kubernetes was installed following instruction at [link] https://vitux.com/install-and-deploy-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/ [link]

Comment: We are trying to install che using the below link. https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/running-che-locally/#setting-up-a-local-kubernetes-or-openshift-cluster

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout by setting `--k8spodreadytimeout=500000`

[1] https://github.com/che-incubator/chectl

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Following https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/13871 (which is for minishift)

```
kubectl delete namespaces che 

chectl server:start --platform minikube
```

give it a try

Comment: Can't use minikube because it can't be installed on a vm. My setup is on a ubuntu vm.

Answer (score -1):

I hope by now you would have installed Eclipse Che on Kubernetes successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Rajsekar for your offer. I am still struggling. I have enabled Minikube and all seems to be fine with it. However when i run,   `chectl server:start --platform minikube`    it fails with     `× Start minikube
      → Timed out
      Verify if minikube ingress addon is enabled
      Enable minikube ingress addon
      Retrieving minikube IP and domain for ingress URLs
Error: Command timed out after 180000 milliseconds: minikube start --memory=4096 --cpus=4 --disk-size=50g
Timed out`

Comment: Hi @rajasekar, I am getting the below error while deploying CHE -- [23:50:15] ✅  Post installation checklis [failed]
 [23:50:15] → Timeout: there are no pods in the namespace: eclipse-che, selector: app=che,component=postgres. Check Eclipse Che logs for details. Consider increasing error recheck timeout with --k8spoderrorrechecktimeut flag.

Comment: I deleted the parts which, at most, should have been a comment.